# NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail on UITextView removing new line breaks

Tags: ios, uitextview, newline, truncation, nstextcontainer

I have a UITextView with attributedText that has multiple new line breaks included in its attributed string.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *info = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];

NSAttributedString *title = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", item.title] attributes:titleAttributes];

NSAttributedString *description = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n", description] attributes:descriptionAttributes]

[info appendAttributedString:bioItemTitle];
[info appendAttributedString:bioItemDescription];

textView.attributedText = info;
```

I've set the lineBreakMode of the textView's textContainer to NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail.

```
textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

The textView's textContainer also has a maximum number of lines.

```
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 8;
```

The problem arises when the 8th line of the textView is a new line, and not a line of characters. The textContainer truncates by removing the new line and replacing it with the next line of written characters.

How do I preserve the new line while still setting a lineBreakMode?

[See screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaSgo.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `UILabel` instead of `UITextView`. It seems to play nicer in regard to truncating a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Random things to try on the off chance you haven't already that aren't even solutions but maybe workarounds, and may not work anyway, but whatever:

- Change the `maximumNumberOfLines` to `0` and rely on frames/autolayout to size the text view and its container, perhaps in combination with setting the text container's `heightTracksTextView` property to `true`
- Insert horizontal whitespace or invisibles at the beginning of lines that otherwise only contain a newline *#hacky*